# tab bar controller with view controllers

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5

Does anyone know how to have a tab bar controller and then have a series of screens connected to the tab.  These screens would still have the tab bar controller in them with out adding another tab for these screens.  I read it was not possible to have a navigation controller inside of a tab bar controller but the facebook app has exactly what i'm trying to reproduce.  Help!

Here is a picture of what i'm talking about:
[image: storyboard]
<sub>(source: [papiobeads.com](http://www.papiobeads.com/trial.png))</sub>

If you look at this picture i'm trying to figure out how to add view controllers after the "design" tab but i still want them to have the tab bar on the pages but go back and forth smoothly like if there was a navigation controller present.  I have seen this done in the Facebook app i just don't know how to replicate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I read it was not possible to have a navigation controller inside of a tab bar controller" => Where did you read that ? You can set navigation controllers on the tabs.

Simply drag the Navigation controller component on the storyboard and link it from the tab bar controller.

[image]

Comment: I feel pretty stupid.  I originally just tried this out before I started researching and I had enabled unchecked on the controller part....

Comment: If I ever find you, I'm gonna KISS you!